# Cannot get playlist ID in response object when creating a Spotify playlist

Tags: javascript, spotify

The playlist object I get in response to POST https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists should include a playlist 'id' property.

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/create-playlist/

However, the response object I get has an 'id' property giving the user id instead of the playlist id.

I am able to create the playlist, but without knowing playlist id I'm unable to add tracks to it.

My code:

```
return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists`,
    {
      headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({name:playlistName})
    }).then(response => response.json()
    ).then(jsonReponse => {
      const playlistId = jsonResponse.id;
      console.log(playlistId); // not getting playlist id!
      console.log(jsonResponse);
      console.log(trackURIs);
      console.log(accessToken);
    });
```

The scope is public by default.

Is anyone else not able to access playlist id after creating a playlist?

Comment: Syntax error/typo (mentioned below) aside - that's strange. A POST to that URL should return the Playlist Object from Spotify's API. Can you post the full response?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error:

).then(jsonReponse => {

Missing 's'